# Difference between null and empty: strange bug

Tags: php, string

I have a PHP function to return a space or not.

In the program, the constant **CURRENCY_HASSPACE = 1**

Here is the function :

```
function a($has_space=null){  //by default, it depends of the constant value

   if($has_space=='' or $has_space==' '){  //space if passed to the function
          $space=$has_space;
    }else{ //space depending the Constant
          $space=(CURRENCY_HASSPACE==1)?' ':'';
    }
    return $space;
}
```

**Results :**

```
a(' ') => space (OKAY)
a(null) => no space  (KO)
```

**but if I try :**

```
a(1) => space (OKAY)
```

but why a(null) doesn't return also a space? I don't understand..

Any idea?

Comment: `null == ''` evaluates to true, so it returns null. You should use a triple equals-sign for comparison: `if ($has_space === '' || $has_space === ' ')` ...

Comment: null != empty. see [`is_null`](http://php.net/is_null)

Comment: @mistermartin yes so if has_space=null, then it should go in the "else", no?

Comment: @Julien no, because a null string is not empty. null is a type of value that simply means "no value"

Comment: @Julien No, because your first comparison checks `if ($has_space == '' /* or blah */)`. So if you input null, that evaluates to true and it sets `$space` to the input value (The first block, not the else)

Comment: okay understood, thank you both!

Comment: This may be helpful to look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.  See how empty, isset and is_null compare to one another.